# redirect output from a dos exe to vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, command-prompt, io-redirection

i have an dos exe which take argument, perform its functions and display the output in dos.

i need to call the dos file from vb passing the argument without showing the dos window, and get the return values directed to vb textbox.

anyone know how i can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "DOS"? MS-DOS hasn't been around for quite a few years. Are you talking about a *Console* application? That's not DOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Process` class to execute the command line utility and set it to redirect `StandardOutput` to a .NET stream that you read from.